# How to find a package by its import path on maven central?

Tags: gradle, import, dependencies, package, maven-central

I'm working on a project that (until now) did not use dependency-manager (now Gradle)

I try to resolve the dependencies and add them to the `build.gradle`. Now I found a class, where I can't find the corresponding package

```
org.apache.tools.tar.TarEntry
```

Now, given the information from above, how can I find a packe that contains that class?

Answer (score 1):

Maven central has an advanced search form [here](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav). You can specify a Classname you are lookin for and it'll show you all the jar with such a class. [Here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.apache.tools.tar.TarEntry%22) is the output for your `org.apache.tools.tar.TarEntry` class.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude non-exact matches like `hudson.org.apache.tools.tar.TarEntry`? Is there a way to sort by last modification date?